# Prove that: $\displaystyle\int_\Omega (Av)\cdot (Av)\,dx\leq \int_\Omega (Av)\cdot (\|A\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}v)\,dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

$A$ is a symmetric tensor in $L^\infty(\Omega)^{n\times n}$, with $\Omega$ a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that

$\displaystyle\int_\Omega (Av)\cdot (Av)\,dx\leq \int_\Omega (Av)\cdot (\|A\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}v)\,dx$

where $v\in L^2(\Omega)^n$.

Comment: I edited my question with a specific space where live the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to the question, whether for symmetric $A$
$$
\|Ax\|_2^2\le \|A\|_\infty \cdot x^TAx
$$
holds for all $x$.

This is not true without positive definiteness of $A$ (take $A=-I$).

It is true for positive definite $A$:
$$
\|Ax\|_2^2 =\|A^{1/2}A^{1/2}x\|_2^2 \le \|A^{1/2}\|_2^2 \cdot \|A^{1/2}x\|_2^2
\le  \|A^{1/2}\|_2^2\cdot x^TAx.
$$
Since $A^{1/2}$ is symmetric positive definite
$$
\|A^{1/2}\|_2^2 = \lambda_\max(A^{1/2})^2 = \lambda_\max(A) \le \|A\|_\infty,
$$
which is the claim. Note that we can use any matrix norm on $\mathbb R^{n,n}$ instead of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.